# updated value in grid is not shown at java spring controller

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, dojo, dojox.grid

I have a enhanced grid, i want to edit the grid contents and once clicked on Update link, i have to pass newly typed values to the java spring controller where i have logic to save updated values in database. But issue is after i type the value in enhanced grid i need to click somewhere in the grid or make focus on other field so that newly typed value is passed to the spring controller. If i type the new value and the cell is in edit mode and directly click on UPDATE link present in column4 of grid, the old value is passed to the spring controller. Please suggest what changes to be made so that once the mouse is out of the focus of the cell, the newly typed value should save in store and that value should be sent to spring controller when UPDATE link is clicked on column4 of grid.

Please find the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/740L0y43/7/

enhanced grid code:

```
require(['dojo/_base/lang', 'dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid', 'dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore', 'dijit/form/Button', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/aspect', 'dojo/domReady!'],

function (lang, EnhancedGrid, ItemFileWriteStore, Button, dom, aspect) {
    /*set up data store*/
    var data = {
        identifier: "id",
        items: [{
            id : 1,
            col2 : "aa",
            col3 : "bb",
            col4 : "cC"
         }]
    };

    var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: data
    });

    /*set up layout*/
    var layout = [
        [{
            'name': 'Column 1',singleClickEdit:'true', editable:'true',
                'field': 'id',
                'width': '100px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 2',singleClickEdit:'true', editable:'true',
                'field': 'col2',
                'width': '100px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 3',singleClickEdit:'true', editable:'true',
                'field': 'col3',
                'width': '200px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 4',formatter: updateDetails,
                'field': 'col4',
                'width': '150px'
        }]
    ];

    /*create a new grid*/
    var grid = new EnhancedGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        sortInfo: -1,

    });


    /*append the new grid to the div*/
    grid.placeAt("gridDiv");

    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    grid.startup();

    aspect.after(grid, 'renderRow', grid.sort);

    var id = 2;

    var button = new Button({
        onClick: function () {
            console.log(arguments);
            store.newItem({
                id: id,
                col2: "col2-" + id,
                col3: "col3-" + id,
                col4: "col4-" + id
            });
            id++;
        }
    }, "addRow");
});

   var updateDetails = function(value, rowIndex) {
        var col2 = this.grid.getItem(rowIndex).col2;
       alert("col2 updated value : " + col2);
     return "<a href=\"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/updateInfo.htm?col2="+col2 +"\">" + "UPDATE";
            };
```

spring controller code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView updateInfo(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute MyDTO myDto,
            @RequestParam("col2") String col2, @RequestParam("col2") String col2){

    System.out.println("col2 value: " + col2);
    System.out.println("col3 value: " + col3);

    //when i type some value in COlumn2/Column3 of enhanced grid and column is still in edit mode then on click of UPDATE , new value is not passed to spring controller, its passing the old value.
...
    ...
    //logic to save in DB


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
     return "<a href=\"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/updateInfo.htm?col2="+col2 +"\">" + "UPDATE";
```

is returning an anchor with the href as "/contextPath/updateInfo.html?col2=aa". That renders it and that's *it*; that URL is never changing. Then, when you click on UPDATE, it sends what was in there when the page was rendered, not what the current value in your table is.

If you want to have the current value be sent, you should have your href be "#" and have an onclick="updateValue(1)" like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="updateValue(1)">UPDATE</a>
```

where 1 is the row number.

Then, in your update value function, you'd send an ajax request to update the value. Since you're using dojo, check this out: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/ajax/

Here's what your function might look like (some pseudo code, some comments to describe behavior):

```
function updateValue(rowNum){
    //var row = data.items.getRow(rowNum); or something like this
    //Call ajax here and send the new row values
}
```

Comment: <a href=\"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/updateInfo.htm?col2dummy="+col2 +"\"> where col2 has updated value , can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/740L0y43/7/ . When col2 is updated and click on UPDATE link new updated value is shown in alert box.
And i have done in the same way as you suggested,i cannot use ajax in this method as when the grid loads i need to show the update icon and that is done using a href link followed by the image as shown in fiddle. Please suggest is there any other possible ways to achieve this. @dubhov

Comment: Right, so you have javscript alerting you to the new value. But, the important part here is what your <a> tag is doing, right? So that href attribute is never being updated no matter what. There is no data-binding or anything fancy going on here; the <a> tag's href value contains the col2 value when the table is _rendered_. That means, whatever's on the page is what's on the page until you change it.

Comment: Also, in response to "I can't use ajax": you definitely can. You can make ajax perform a GET request the same way that your <a> is doing, and it will give you the same result as clicking the UPDATE link. Your 2 options (IMO...there might be more) are: 1. Use ajax to perform a get request with the same URL that UPDATE references or 2. Re-render the UPDATE <a> to point to the new value (which I don't recommend, and I feel like is over-engineering it.  I'll be happy to help with option 1 if you're having issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

After messing with dojo for about an hour, and struggling with dojo's scoping and how to call a function that has access to the data grid and/or it's data store (sorry..I had 0 experience with dojo before this question)...here's your easy way out, OP:

http://jsfiddle.net/hm8gpz6o/

The important parts:

1. EnhancedGrid was *NOT* re-rendering the formatter generated cell when your data store was updated. This seems like a problem with dojo's EnhancedGrid.
2. I added the following (onApplyCellEdit will fire when a cell is updated):

   ```
   /*create a new grid*/
   var grid = new EnhancedGrid({
       id: 'grid',
       store: store,
       structure: layout,
       sortInfo: -1,
       onApplyCellEdit: function(inValue, inRowIndex, inFieldIndex){
           refreshGrid();
       }
   });
   ```
3. And finally, refreshGrid() will force a re-render of the whole grid. I hate that I have to do this:

   ```
   function refreshGrid(){
       grid.startup();   
   }
   ```

Please see the fiddle for the full working example.

Comment: sorry to say that its not working ,issue is we need to make the focus out side the edited cell to get the updated value at the controller. If the focus is in cell with editable mode and we change the value and click on update ,its passing the old value to the spring controller, i need to click somewhere else in the page to make focus out of the cell and then click on update link to get the updated value. The way you mentioned above also doesn't work until we make focus out of the editable cell. +1Appreciate ur effort.Do we need to write onFocusout to solve this issue. Please suggest. @dubhov

Comment: The event I provided is the most granular one I could find. There's no "keyUp" event for grid cells that I could find. This is seriously the best _I_ can do given that you're tied to dojo (which I'm seriously not liking after this adventure). Good luck.

Comment: hmm, unfortunately it doesn't worked. even i tried with all possible ways , but could not able to get the updated value without focus being completely removed from the updated cell. Thanks for your time. @dubhov

Comment: So, the value is updated only after you click away from the cell.  I realize that's not exactly what you want, but given the JS framework that you're tied to, that's _just_ how it works. The options are: do it in ajax or figure out if there's a keyUp handler and re-render the grid...on every keyup....which sounds horrible.

Comment: yes..please see my initial post which also says "But issue is after i type the value in enhanced grid i need to click somewhere in the grid or make focus on other field so that newly typed value is passed to the spring controller.". i tried all possible ways bit of no luck :(. but i have to keep on trying till i get the solution..@dubhov